# How to sum a dataframe column of lists of numbers in string form?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-wrangling

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
| Unit     | Charges                         |
|----------|---------------------------------|
| DW01-100 | trash(15); pest(2)              |
| DW01-101 | trash(15); pest(3)              |
| DW01-102 | garage(150); trash(15); pest(3) |
| DW01-103 | pest(3); trash(15)              |
| DW01-104 | trash(15); pest(3)              |
| DW11-407 | trash(15); pest(3); carport(35) |
| DW11-408 | garage(200); trash(15); pest(3) |
| DW11-409 | trash(15); pest(3)              |
| DW11-410 | carport(35); trash(15); pest(3) |
| DW11-411 | NaN                             |
```

I want to take all the charges, which are the numbers in parentheses, then sum them and store them in a column. So far I am using a regex findall

```
df['Charges'] = df['Charges'].str.findall(r"\((.+?)\)")
```

to extract all the numbers in parentheses. Now I have a list of numbers stored as text in each cell.

I'm getting stuck stuck on the next step, which is to convert each number string into a float and sum the list of floats for each cell in the column.
The desired output should look like this:

| Unit | Charges | Summed Charges |
| --- | --- | --- |
| DW01-100 | trash(15); pest(2) | 17 |
| DW01-101 | trash(15); pest(3) | 18 |
| DW01-102 | garage(150); trash(15); pest(3) | 168 |

So far I have tried `apply` like this:

```
def charge_sum(charge_list):
    return sum([float(i) for i in charge_list])

    df['Summed Charges'] = df['Charges'].apply(charge_sum)
```

This returns TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable.

What am I doing wrong here? I thought `apply` passes the cell as an argument to the `charge_sum` function, so the input should be a single list of strings, and then the list comprehension should convert each `str` to `float` and the return the sum. When I put added this to the function for debugging:
`print(charge_list)` it seems to print the entire column

```
['15', '2']
['15', '3']
['150', '15', '3']
['3', '15']
['15', '3']
['3', '15']
['15']
['15', '3']
['15', '3', '-101.75', '150']
['15', '3', '-88.4']
['15', '3', '-88']
['15', '3', '-89']
['3', '15']
['15', '3', '150']
['15', '2']
['15', '3']
nan
```

instead of just a printing the first row ['15', '2'] before erroring out. Why is the whole column being passed to the apply function at once, instead of a single cell?

In addition, how do I avoid applying the function if the cell contains `nan`? I suppose I could just `fillna(0)`, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `.str.extractall()`:

```
df["Summed Charges"] = (
    df["Charges"]
    .str.extractall(r"\((\d+)\)")
    .astype(int)
    .groupby(level=0)
    .sum()
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
       Unit                          Charges  Summed Charges
0  DW01-100               trash(15); pest(2)            17.0
1  DW01-101               trash(15); pest(3)            18.0
2  DW01-102  garage(150); trash(15); pest(3)           168.0
3  DW01-103               pest(3); trash(15)            18.0
4  DW01-104               trash(15); pest(3)            18.0
5  DW11-407  trash(15); pest(3); carport(35)            53.0
6  DW11-408  garage(200); trash(15); pest(3)           218.0
7  DW11-409               trash(15); pest(3)            18.0
8  DW11-410  carport(35); trash(15); pest(3)            53.0
9  DW11-411                              NaN             NaN
```

Comment: Thanks Andrej! This does exactly what I needed. Do you have any explanation for why what I tried failed?

Comment: @saujosai On row `9` you have `NaN` value. So you're trying to iterate over this `NaN` value and you get the TypeError.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach : - convert the series of list to a dataframe, and convert to float using `df.astype`, then take sum on `axis=1`:

```
s = df['Charges'].str.findall(r"\((.+?)\)").dropna()
df['Summed Charges'] = pd.DataFrame(s.tolist(),index=s.index).astype(float).sum(1)
```

---

```
print(df)

       Unit                          Charges  Summed Charges
0  DW01-100               trash(15); pest(2)            17.0
1  DW01-101               trash(15); pest(3)            18.0
2  DW01-102  garage(150); trash(15); pest(3)           168.0
3  DW01-103               pest(3); trash(15)            18.0
4  DW01-104               trash(15); pest(3)            18.0
5  DW11-407  trash(15); pest(3); carport(35)            53.0
6  DW11-408  garage(200); trash(15); pest(3)           218.0
7  DW11-409               trash(15); pest(3)            18.0
8  DW11-410  carport(35); trash(15); pest(3)            53.0
9  DW11-411                              NaN             NaN
```